# Getting ClientSide Piplines to fire

Tags: experience-editor, pipelines

I am on Sitecore.NET 8.0 (rev. 160115)
January 15, 2016
.NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000.

I am trying to follow these instructions on [how to fix a fixed position navigation](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2017/03/24/sitecore-experience-ribbon-header/)

So, I created the Js file & I went into core and setup the following.

[image]

Funny thing is I don't think any of the piplines are executing (or I really don't understand what is going on)

I tried to add the following to my pipeline and an existing one GetCommands.js for debugging purposes

```
window.hello = 'hello';
Sitecore.hello = 'hello';
console.log('hello');
alert('hello');
```

When in the console  window.hello and Sitecore.hello were undefined.

Comment: It could be these pipelines do not work/fire in 8.0, since the original article suggest it does not work with SC9 either so may not be tested (look at the comments). IMO, a _much_ simpler solution is to forget making the header static in Experience Editor mode and instead use an override style for EE mode to make it inline.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean to put code in the back end to determine if Sitecore.IsExperienceEditor then apply style (or remove style)

Comment: Thank you for your reply ... I just have a problem with" pipelines do not work/fire in 8.0" since there were 6 of them with the standard installation.

Comment: I haven't used those pipelines, so it's just a guess on my part. Personally, I add a "is-experience-editor" class on the `body` tag and then this allows me to provide override styles in the CSS (i.e. set the header back to `position: initial`)

Comment: So... I used your approach and it worked.  Thank you.  However I am still curious as to why the pipelines aren't firing so I am going to leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I'm using `debugger;` if I want to debug something in Experience Editor client (SPEAK) pipelines:

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor) {
  return {
    priority: 1,
    execute: function (context) {
      try {
        debugger;
        ExperienceEditor.Web.updateHtml5Cache();
      } catch (err) {}
    }
  };
});
```

then you need to open Developer Tools and refresh the page and then you should be able to catch this breakpoint:
[image]

You'll need to restart your instance (IIS reset/app pool recycle) if you can't catch breakpoint. SPEAK tries to bundle client pipeline processors into one file and site restart should fix this if it misses your changes.

You can also find more information here: blog.coates.dk/2014/02/01/speak-simple-pipeline/